# Return 1 array of several api call

Tags: javascript, api

Is it possible to create a function who return an array of result of several api call ?

Instead of this :

```html
var func1;
var func2;
var func3;

apicall1().then((res) => {
  func1 = res;
});

apicall1("string").then((res) => {
  func2 = res;
});

apicall1(int).then((res) => {
  func3 = res;
});
```

Have something like this :

```html
var result = [];

var Json = "{
 "functions": [{
  "name": "apicall1",
  "args": null
 }, {
  "name": "apicall2",
  "args": "string"
 }, {
  "name": "apicall2",
  "args": [0, "string"]
 }]
}";

MyFunction(Json) {
  for (i = 0; i < functions.lenght; i += 1) {
    functions[i].name(functions[i].args).then((res) => { result.push(res); });
  }
  return result;
}
```

I juste search something to avoid to have X callapi one behind the other.

Thanks ;D

Comment: Look up `Promise.all(func1, func2, func3).then(globalResult)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get results in an array:

```
Promise.all([apicall1(), apicall1("string"), apicall1(int)])
  .then(results => {
    // Destructure the results into separate variables
    let [func1, func2, func3] = results;

    //access the results here
  });
```

Comment: However, this will fire all API calls simultaneously. I think OP wants them one after the other, because they're calls to the same API.

Comment: @JeremyThille -- The statement is not clear to me. Does OP wants the calls simultaneously, or he doesn't? :/

Comment: It's not clear to me either, but it would make sense that the same API is not called 3 times (or 100 times) simultaneously.

Comment: Sorry.
Here i can call simultaneously :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
Promise.all([ api1,api2,api2,...]).then(function(results){
}).catch(function(err){
})
```

result will be an array with all responses in respective indexes. Here one thing you need to handle is exception. if any of the API call occurs in any kind of exception it will go to catch.

Comment: Same comment as for @31piy : this will fire all API calls simultaneously. I think OP wants them one after the other, because they're calls to the same API.

Comment: then OP can use [async queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async.queue)   with the limit of 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger the calls one after the other, you can use `async/await` :

https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9

```
let result = [];

let funcs = [{
        "name": "apicall1",
        "args": null
    }, {
        "name": "apicall2",
        "args": "string"
    }, {
        "name": "apicall2",
        "args": [0, "string"]
    }]

async makeCalls() {
  for (let func of funcs) {
    let res = await func.name(func.args)
    result.push(res)
  }
  return result;
}

makeCalls()
```